# BrainTree Credit Card details to be submitted on BrainTree portal only

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, braintree

Is there anyway to have the CreditCard details entered by the customer on the BrainTree portal itself rather than that we collect the info on our site and then redirect to BrainTree?

We're working on a high-visibility e-commerce platform for a major consultancy and if this is not possible we would have to revert to some other option like Authorize.net which has a SimpleCheckout kindof option. We've researched a lot on the net but couldnt find any info relevant to this.
It would really be a shame if we need to do this, cause we have the entire application almost build and ready to be rolled out. The technology stack is Drupal/MySql. This is the only blocker posed by the stakeholders.

Can anyone please help? (Anyone from the BrainTree team please )